# Is LINQ to XML order dependent and can you number results with it?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-xml

So, my first question, is [LINQ to XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_XML) order dependent?

Given the XML (simplified version of the actual file):

```
<root>
    <dl Id='111' Or='true' />
    <dl Id='112' Or='false' />
</root>
```

The container:

```
public class root
{
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Or { get; set; }
}
```

The reader code:

```
var t = a.DescendantsAndSelf("root").Descendants("dl").Select(b => new root
{
    Id = int.Parse(b.Attribute("Id").Value),
    Or = bool.Parse(b.Attribute("Or").Value)
});
```

Will the root elements in `t` always be in the order they were read out of the file? If not, is there any way to enforce ordering?

The second question, is there any way to automatically add a number to the reader code that says whether it was the first, second, third, etc. root to be read out of the XML? So in this example have it so `t` would contain two elements with the values

1. dl.Position = 1, dl.Id = 111, dl.Or = true
2. dl.Position = 2, dl.Id = 112, dl.Or = false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, LINQ is "order dependent". Your objects get created in the order in which they appear in the XML file.

To get the position, use the version of `Select` which includes an index:

```
var t = a.DescendantsAndSelf("root").Descendants("dl").Select((b,idx) => new root
{
    Id = int.Parse(b.Attribute("Id").Value),
    Or = bool.Parse(b.Attribute("Or").Value),
    Position = idx+1
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had no idea it was that simple to add a index to LINQ

Comment: Neither did I until somebody else explained it to me on SO ;)